# Conditional replacement in pandas for each row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, series

I am probably doing something very simple, but I cant figure out the trick there.

I have a dataframe, and I want to replace the values in a particular column that exceed a value from zero with some random value. I had thought this was a way of achieving this:

```
self.dfile['foo'] = np.where(self.dfile['foo'] >= 0, random.uniform(4, 9), self.dfile['foo'])
```

It seems to be giving the same random value across all values that exceed 0. How do I get different values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.random.uniform`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html) with specifying length by length of `DataFrame`:

```
v = np.random.uniform(4, 9, size=len(self.dfile))
self.dfile['foo'] = np.where(self.dfile['foo'] >= 0, v,self.dfile['foo'])
```

**Sample**:

```
np.random.seed(123)

dfile = pd.DataFrame({
         'foo':[0,5.1,1,0,20.4,10.7],
})

v = np.random.uniform(4, 9, size=len(dfile))

dfile['foo1'] = np.where(dfile['foo'] >= 0, v, dfile['foo'])
dfile['foo2'] = np.where(dfile['foo'].between(0, 10), v ,dfile['foo'])
print (dfile)

    foo      foo1       foo2
0   0.0  7.482346   7.482346
1   5.1  5.430697   5.430697
2   1.0  5.134257   5.134257
3   0.0  6.756574   6.756574
4  20.4  7.597345  20.400000
5  10.7  6.115532  10.700000
```

Comment: Thanks. Would this also function?

`self.dfile['foo'] = np.where(self.dfile['foo'] >= 0 and self.dfile['foo'] <= 10, v, self.dfile['foo'])`

Comment: @tandem - You are close, need `&` for bitwise AND and also `()` like `self.dfile['foo'] = np.where((self.dfile['foo'] >= 0) & (self.dfile['foo'] <= 10), v, self.dfile['foo'])`

Comment: @tandem - or better `self.dfile['foo'] = np.where(self.dfile['foo'].between(0, 10), v,self.dfile['foo'])`

Answer (score 2):

`random.uniform(4, 9)` returns an integer, which `np.where` then broadcasts across all rows. Instead, use `np.random`, which gives an array of specified length:

```
self.dfile['foo'] = np.where(self.dfile['foo'] >= 0,
                             np.random.uniform(4, 9, len(self.dfile.index)),
                             self.dfile['foo'])
```